# How do I create a "Details" button in Microsoft Access?

Tags: ms-access

I'm new to using Microsoft Access, and I'm having trouble restricting a report's output to only the single row I'm interested in.

My organization has a relatively small client list, where a little of their information is used frequently (like their name and account status), and much is used infrequently but still important (like home phone and incident reports).

The way I want to display this information is to have a form that shows a list of our active clients with their most common information, and then has a "Details" button at the end of the client info for when people need to see the rest of that client's information.

So far, I've successfully made a form that links to an "ActiveClients_rpt" report that shows the most common info, and I've made another form that links to a "ClientDetails_rpt" report that shows all the detailed info. My problem is that when I try to restrict the results in the Client Details report by the user input in the Active Clients form, either I have to use a very unaesthetic option (like an ugly combo box that replicates the list of names the user can already see), or (if I try to do something like add a button inside a report) the form sends me the information of **every** client's detailed info, when I only want the info of the one client.

Is there some way I can use a report (or some other option) to tell Access to only pull information from the row in a list the button is located on? I've tried doing things like making an embedded macro using the OpenForm command to open my ClientDetails_form form with `[Forms]![ClientDetails_form]![ID]` or `[Forms]![ClientDetails_form]![ID]=[Me].[ID]` as a Where Condition (where `ID` is the client's ID #), but everything I've tried has either resulted in an error or not restricted the report like I want it to.

Comment: I am confused by your narrative. Do you want to open a filtered report from a form or do you want to open a filtered form from a report? Buttons on report only work in ReportView not PrintPreview. OpenForm or OpenReport can certainly be executed from a button with code that pulls ID from record that has focus.

Comment: I have a form (let's call it "BriefForm" that calls and displays a report (let's call it "BriefReport") which has some information on all clients, and I want BriefReport to open another report (let's call it DetailedReport) that has all information on only one client. I don't want to put the selection buttons on BriefForm because we have a variable number of clients and I won't be able to predict how many "Details" buttons to display.

Comment: There would be only 1 "Details" button with code: `DoCmd.OpenReport "DetailedReport", acViewPreview, , "ID=" & Me.ID` or `DoCmd.OpenForm "DetailedForm", , , "ID=" & Me.ID`

Comment: Thank you! This works wonderfully. Also, I realized part of my problem is that I didn't realize you had to actually insert a field into a report's detail, and not just include it as a data source. Score one for being a newb! Now I just need to figure out how to "clean up" the report so that the client ID (which is irrelevant info) doesn't display for the user...

Comment: Just set textbox Visible property to No. Yes, unlike forms, reports are little more demanding and field must be in a textbox for code to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty complicated without seeing your actual database, but I did a video on something similar that might help here https://youtu.be/nNUjmH72OfI. You basically set a click event in the 'Event' tab of the Properties window while your 'Detail' button is selected (in form design view). You click on the builder button (button with three dots) and either use the Macro Builder or the Code Builder to type out the VBA. The Macro Builder is the simplest way in this case.

That's pretty vague, I admit. But hopefully the video helps.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm glad to even know that it's complicated - it makes me feel better to know that I'm not the only one that struggles to accomplish this.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've been trying to use your method, but when I use the code in your example, I get a "Type Mismatch" error. I suspected it might be because the field I'm using is numerical and your example had the field in quotes, so I removed the quotes and it pulled up the report, but didn't apply any filtering. 

EDIT: sorry, should have said I removed the quotes and it gave me an invalid value error, so I added quotes to both and it ran, but didn't filter.

Comment: Sorry, another update. Your method works great! I didn't realize you had to paste a field into the detail section of a report in order to invoke it in an event (I had assumed that including a field as a data source was sufficient). Probably should have figured that out earlier.